# calling javascript function to include stylesheet fails

Tags: javascript, css

Here's the fail I'm having -- the 'sitePath' is a javascript variable at global file scope:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"     
          href="javascript:getJval('sitePath')/rb_UI_styles.css" />
```

Here is getJval():

```
  function getJval(theVal)
  {
      return theVal;
  }
```

Originally I tried this but it didn't work:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"     
          href="javascript:sitePath/rb_UI_styles.css" />
```

I read a bunch of SO posts, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179882/getbaseurl-javascript-call-function-in-a-href) one, many of these posts I've read have an 'href' that gets set by using the

```
     href="javascript:someFunc(someparam)"
```

syntax.

However, this syntax to call a javascript function to set an 'href' is **not** working for me in the href for pulling in a stylesheet:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"     
          href="javascript:getJval('sitePath')/rb_UI_styles.css" />
```

Can't figure out why.  I know the stylesheet can be pulled in because if I replace the above with the actual URL to the CSS file, the styles appear successfully on the web page.

Does this javascript:function() syntax *not* work to set an href in a stylesheet link, for some reason?

Comment: vheck this link http://thudjs.tumblr.com/post/637855087/stylesheet-onload-or-lack-thereof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you can't use JavaScript to output the file path to the Stylesheet inside the `href` attribute. When you use JavaScript for the `href` of an anchor tag, the JavaScript function is only called when you click on the anchor tag. For a link element, it doesn't process the JavaScript at all.

If you want to dynamically load the CSS, you'll either need to use PHP to echo out the correct file path before the page is created or call a JavaScript function which will insert a link element into the DOM as @Pranav Ram suggested.

```
function loadStyleSheet( path, fn, scope ) {
   var head = document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[0]
       link = document.createElement( 'link' );
   link.setAttribute( 'href', path );
   link.setAttribute( 'rel', 'stylesheet' );
   link.setAttribute( 'type', 'text/css' );
   head.appendChild(link);
}
```